# href in <a> tag not working inside <li> DJANGO

Tags: python, html, css, django

href in a tag inside li don't woriking. It does not redirect me to /sub1/.
This is my code:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4682B4;
  height: 80px;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar .nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar .nav li.nav-item {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 95px;
}

.navbar .nav li.nav-item>a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar .nav li.nav-item>a:hover {
  background-color: #B0C4DE;
}

.dropdown a:focus {
  background-color: #B0C4DE;
}

.dropdown a:focus~.dropdown-container {
  max-height: 500px;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in;
}

.dropdown-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #4682B4;
  color: #B0C4DE;
}

.dropdown-container a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 250px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}

.dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #B0C4DE;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav" id="primary-nav">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="/index/">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="#">Servicios</a>
        <div class="dropdown-container">
          <div class="dropdown-inner">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="{% url 'Datos:sub1' %}">Submenu 1</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">Submenu2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="">Agenda</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="">¿Quiénes somos?</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="/contact/">Contacto</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from Applications.Datos import views

app_name = "Datos"

urlpatterns = [
    re_path('^sub1/', views.Datos, name='sub1'),
    path('search/', views.buscar),
]
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import request

# Create your views here.
def Datos(request):
    return render(request, template_name='datos.html')
```

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see the [help] and [ask]. The character threshold is there so you post better questions, please don't post gibberish just to circumvent that. "It does not redirect me to /sub1/" where then does it redirect you? Please be more _clear_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using correct syntax.

```
<a href="{% url '<app_name>:<view_name>' %}"></a>
```

Where <view_name> is the view name you gave in urls.py for the app in which template is made. like here:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from home import views

app_name = "home"
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home_view, name='productsPage'),
    re_path('^wishlist/', views.wishlist_view, name='wishlistPage'),
]
```

The name of the view is `wishlistPage` and app is `home` so you write to make a link to that page redirect:

```
<a href="{% url 'home:wishlistPage' %}"></a>
```

---

## Update

`sub1` is the path of your MAIN VIEW FOR THAT APP when you want to visit `<youwebsite>/sub1`. In that case the urls.py for this app is incorrect.
Edit this `urls.py` to be like this:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from Applications.Datos import views

app_name = "Datos"

urlpatterns = [
    re_path('', views.Datos, name='sub1'),  # UPDATE: LET IT BE BLANK
    path('search/', views.buscar),
]
```

And update your main `urls.py` to b like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    [...your other urls...],
    re_path(r'^sub1/', include(('Datos.urls', 'Datos'), namespace='Datos')),
]
```

Comment: I made the proposed changes and it still doesn't work. Maybe there is a problem in the css code? @AnuragDhadse

Comment: @LucianoAbatidaga Nope Css doesn't have anything to do with linking. Post your `urls.py` for this app and `view.py` which is responsible for rendering this template.

Comment: Done, I already edit the original post. @AnuragDhadse

Comment: So `sub1` is the name of your view for that app when you want to visit `<youwebsite>/sub1`. In that case the urls.py for this app is incorrect. I will update my answer. wait.

Comment: @LucianoAbatidaga Updated! Check if it now works?

Comment: No, it still doesn't work. I made the changes but I still have the same problem. When I touch the menu, it opens but does not redirect me to the page. Will the HTML code be okay? @AnuragDhadse

Comment: @LucianoAbatidaga Check the terminal for any outputs, see if something fishy when you click on the link. Also make sure you use the noCapitalization like: `datos` **ONLY** if app name is `datos`.

Comment: No, no error in the terminal. The name of the app is Datos. @AnuragDhadse

Comment: @LucianoAbatidaga Are you sure your template starts with <html> tag and all that (just making sure). also if your template file (`datos.html`) is in templates folder of `Datos` app, use `templates/Datos.html` when retruning from Datos view function. And what is your project name?

Comment: Yes, everything is fine. Moreover, when I enter the link directly, the page works, but when I try to enter through the menu, it does not redirect me.
The project is called Plataforma.
@AnuragDhadse

Comment: @LucianaAbatidaga Its really confusing however. I would suggest you to recheck everything and maybe restart the server. You probably require debugging which none of our community members can do. We can only solve errors and incorrect code. So get someone you know and do it on a Zoom Call. :)

Answer (score 0):

It won't work like this. You have to call it like this. in Django while linking html files/pages we use a slightly different approach.

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'sub1' %}">SubMenu</a>
```

Comment: I made the proposed changes and it still doesn't work. Maybe there is a problem in the css code? @MuhammadSameem